# Кнопка Назад в table view controller без navigation controller не работает

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Иерархия у меня такая: TabBarController -> Table View Controller (в качестве tab bar item), далее в хедере этого Table View Controller есть кнопка, по нажатии на которую через segue открывается ещё один table view controller и я туда добавил Navigation bar, в котором есть BarButtonItem. Я в этом последнем table controller в его классе задал для кнопки действие:

```swift
    @IBAction func backbtn(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Но по нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит (хотя нажатие срабатывает - я вставлял туда print, при нажатии на кнопку печатает в логе).

В гугле пишут, что эта команда работает только если есть Navigation Controller, но у меня его некуда вообще вставить. Как мне сделать возврат на предыдущий экран?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методом тыка понял, что сразу после tab controller и перед его итемом надо добавить navigation controller. Я и раньше это пробовал, но моей ошибкой было то, что я использовал отдельный Navigation bar, а там есть собственный.